# typing a special letter in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, symbols, letters

In bibliography of a manuscript, I wish to point out an author whose name is written in the form

[image: grass]

How can I type the last letter of his/her name?

Comment: `author = {Gra{\ss}, T.}`

Comment: If you use `biblatex+biber`, no problem typing **T. Graß**: biber understands natively utf8.